# Comparing Strings in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie, so I apologize if the question is very basic.

How do you check with Haskell if one string is contained in another string, like "banna" and "banana".

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
isElementString :: String -> String -> Bool 
isElementString (y:ys) (x:xs) = elem y (x:xs) && isElementString (ys) (xs)
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simply iterating over the second string, eliminating characters from the first string as you encounter them:

```
isElementString :: String -> String -> Bool
isElementString [] _                            = True
isElementString _ []                            = False
isElementString s@(x : xs) (y : ys) | x == y    = isElementString xs ys
                                    | otherwise = isElementString s ys
```

The idea is to iterate either until we have encountered all characters from the first string or otherwise until we have reached the end of the second string. In the former case, we conclude that the first string was contained in the second string; in the latter case that it was not (as we have still have characters to match in the first string, but no characters left in the second string to match them against).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Could you explain what s and @ mean? 
I didn't have that in class yet, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: @ allows you to bind a matched pattern to another name in addition to the pattern you use. s is the same thing as (x:xs). It's not really needed here, you could just write `otherwise = isElementString (x:xs) ys` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Data.List`'s `isInfixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.

The `isInfixOf` function takes two lists and returns `True` iff the first list is contained, wholly and intact, anywhere within the second.

Example:

```
λ> isInfixOf "Haskell" "I really like Haskell."
True
λ> isInfixOf "Ial" "I really like Haskell."
False
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the test case. "banna" is no infix of "banana".